# JSON.parse with changing variable types, how to use double quotes?

Tags: json, express

I'm trying to make one script to format all possible entities in express. The different entities have different attribute types though. E.g. one entity type has number values for m[attr2], others have string values. How do I get the double quotes only when the attribute type is a string? If I omit the double quotes, string attributes will complain, if I keep them number attributes are saved as strings in the JSON.

I can use if's or a switch and test if attr1 and attr2 are both numbers, then each of them separately and finally the default that both are strings but that seems rather farfetched?

```
const addSelf = require('./Hal');
const url = require('url');

const formatEntity = (req, m, path, attr1, attr2) => {
    let href = url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.get('host'),
        pathname: `/api/${path}/` + m.id
    });
    addSelf(m, href);
    return JSON.parse(`{
        "id": ${m.id},
        "${attr1}": "${m[attr1]}",
        "${attr2}": "${m[attr2]}",
        "_links": ${JSON.stringify(m._links)}
    }`);
}

module.exports = formatEntity;
```

Comment: Why are you building a string to parse with `JSON.parse` in the first place? That's an odd thing to do. Just build the object directly, there's no reason for JSON in the above.

Comment: Separately, **never** handcraft JSON. Instead, if you need a JSON string (for instance, to send across the network), build up the structure you want to send and use `JSON.stringify` to reliably create the JSON for it. `JSON.stringify` knows when to use quotes, what to escape, etc.

Comment: But the literal answer to your question about when to use quotes is `typeof`. E.g., `${typeof m[attr1] === "string" ? /* use quotes */ : /* don't */}` but **don't do that**, use `JSON.stringify` (see above).

Comment: @T.J. Something like this: 
let result = {};
    result.id = m.id;
    result[attr1] = m[attr1];
    result[attr2] = m[attr2];
    result._links = m._links;
    return result;

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Or even: `const result = { id: m.id, [attr1]: m[attr1], [attr2]: m[attr2], _links: m._links }; return result;` (that uses ES2015+ computed property names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know much about JSON yet and didn't know I could build objects directly in JS, this is the better option and this way I avoided the mistakes.